# Что делать, если вместо текста в ComboBox WPF отображаются цифры?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, datagrid, combobox

Пытался понять, почему не работает добавление данных, решил сделать редактирование. При входе на страницу с выведенными данными из SQL в DataGrid, все нормально
[image: один]
После перехода на следующую страницу для редактирования, все ломается. При нажатии на ComboBox появляется привычный текст, который и был заложен в базу данных, но если нажать на что-то, из выпадающего списка, то текст изменяется в набор цифр. При выходе из редактирования, без сохранений, такой поломанный список и остается. При выходе из приложения и последующего запуска, все вновь нормально. Как это исправить?
[image: два]
[image: три]
[image: четыре]

Так же прикрепляю код

**XAML в окне меню:**

```
         <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding Surname}"></DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Firstname}"></DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Отчество" Binding="{Binding Patronymic}"></DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Специальность" Binding="{Binding Speciality.TitleSpeciality}"></DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Группа" Binding="{Binding GroupStudent.TitleGroupStudent}"></DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Логин" Binding="{Binding Authorizationn.AuthorizationnLogin}"></DataGridTextColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Пароль" Binding="{Binding Authorizationn.AuthorizationnPassword}"></DataGridTextColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
     </DataGrid>
```

**C# в окне меню:**

```
public PageAdmin_Menu_Students()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GD.ItemsSource = ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities.GetContext().Students.ToList();
        }
```

**XAML в окне редактирования:**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Фамилия</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Surname}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ></TextBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Имя</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Firstname}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Отчество</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Patronymic}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Гендер</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Gender.TitleGender}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ComboTitleGender" DisplayMemberPath="TitleGender"></ComboBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Специальность</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Speciality.TitleSpeciality}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ComboTitleSpeciality" DisplayMemberPath="TitleSpeciality"></ComboBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Группа</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding GroupStudent.TitleGroupStudent}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ComboGroupStudent" DisplayMemberPath="TitleGroupStudent"></ComboBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Логин</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Authorizationn.AuthorizationnLogin}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >Пароль</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Authorizationn.AuthorizationnPassword}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
```

**C# в окне редактирования:**

```
private Students _currentStudents = new Students();
        public PageAdmin_Menu_Students_Edit(Students selectedStudents)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ComboGroupStudent.ItemsSource = ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities.GetContext().GroupStudent.ToList();
            ComboTitleSpeciality.ItemsSource = ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities.GetContext().Speciality.ToList();
            ComboTitleGender.ItemsSource = ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities.GetContext().Gender.ToList();
            DataContext = _currentStudents;
            if (selectedStudents != null)
                _currentStudents = selectedStudents;
            DataContext = _currentStudents;
        }

        private void Edit_Students_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities.GetContext().Students.Add(_currentStudents);
            try
            {
                ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities.GetContext().SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Информация была изменена!");
                NavigationService.Navigate(new PageAdmin_Menu_Students());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**И как информация выглядит в самом SQL:**
[image: пять]
Модели данных:
[image: шесть]
[image: семь]

Comment: Отладкой по PageAdmin_Menu_Students_Edit пройдитесь. Если отображает цифры, значит вы в ItemsSource их кладете. Модели данных не показали, сложно сказать точнее.

Comment: Добавил модель данных, сколько смог, т.к. репутация не позволяет. Для ComboBox присваивал SelectedIndex. Или я не правильно понял? До этого редактировал/сохранял без внешних ключей, а сейчас даже не знаю что делать. Добавление, к слову, не работает, из-за конфликта инструкции insert с ограничением foreign key. И поменять таблицы не могу, т.к. привязка нужна, и как сохранять значения в другую таблицу - хз

Comment: Код принято здесь текстом вставлять, с картинки код не скопируется, если потребуется. А тип `Gender` - это что?

Comment: Gender - это пол студента м/ж. Пришлось добавить чтобы вышло 15 таблиц для курсовой работы, особо другого нечего было добавлять больше. По этой же базе приходится делать другую курсовую - создание приложения к ней

Comment: Я понимаю, что это значит, я не вижу описание типа. Это `enum` или что? Покажите модели данных, которые после попадания в `ItemsSource` становятся числами.